# Is there a way to extract tcp.option.timestamp value by Nginx

Tags: nginx, tcp

I am doing some research about tcp clock, which is tcp.option.timestamp value. Now I am capturing it by Wireshark, which can not be used in server. I did some research on Nginx, could't find a way to extract tcp clock data by myself.

[image]

So I am curious: Is there a way to extract tcp.option.timestamp value by Nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just can't get tcp.option.timestamp by Nginx, only Linux kernel can.

tcp.option.timestamp is in header of tcp. Nginx can get some header data by [getsockopt API](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsockopt.2.html), which don't include tcp.option.timestamp information. However, [tcp_parse_options() API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_FxHDf4WzSM) can not be used by Nginx.

So, Nginx just can't do it.